# Enable Hyper-V role on a Windows 2008 virtual server

Tags: vmware, hyper-v

I have a VMware virtual machine running Windows 2008 Standard and I would like to enable the Hyper-V role for learning purposes,  but the VMware workstation says my processor doesn't support the virtualization features.

My development machine uses a Core2Duo E8200 which supports hardware virtualization.

Is there any additional setting I must do on VMware to enable this feature?

Comment: You are trying to run a hypervisor from Microsoft in a hypervisor from VMWare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V is a hardware virtualization solution and cannot be run on a virtual machine. If you want to enable Hyper-V you'll need to do that on a X64 machine with hardware virtualization support and the execute disable bit both in the BIOS enabled.

Not all hardware supports virtualization, you can use a little tool from Steve Gibson to see if your system supports it: [Securable](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm)

Hope this helps.